# What cause ''/etc/lsb-release' modified? And how to reproduce it

Tags: 22.04

I observed the below prompt one day when my script is running 'dpkg --configure -a'

```
 Configuration file '/etc/lsb-release'
  ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
  ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
    What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
     Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
     N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
       D     : show the differences between the versions
 The default action is to keep your current version.
```

I made some changes to handle this prompt on my script and would like to test it.
However, this error is no longer seen after I manually resolve it.

Anyway I could reproduce this so I could test my script?

Comment: It depends on what your script did. It is always safe to keep the default version.

Comment: That file IS EXPECTED TO CHANGE for LTS releases, but is NOT EXPECTED TO CHANGE for non-LTS (there are exceptions here though; *artful* or 17.10 changed to 17.10.1 early in its cycle).  Refer https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/amd64/base-files/filelist where you'll note it's part of `base-files` where https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/08/11/ubuntu-22-04-3-lts-released/ shows the ISO release of 22.04.3, but installed systems upgraded in the week before ISO release (*as is normal though it can occur weeks too before*).

Comment: https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/b/base-files/base-files_12ubuntu4.4/changelog  shows the change(s) for 22.04 for that file... which occur for all *architectures* and not just *amd64* as per my prior comment's link (*filelist*)

Comment: Make a change to `/etc/lsb-release`, and force reconfiguration of which ever package caused tge message. See `--reconfigure` in `man dpkg`.

Comment: @waltinator I modified `/etc/lsb-release` then ran `dpkg --configure -a`, however no prompt is shown

Comment: The package (in your case "base-files") is not unpacked on `dpkg --configure`, thus the file is not written, no detection.